# Deal with missing columns in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

We have a large number of databases, all have table `MyTable`, but in some databases there is a column called `MyTable.MyCol1`, and in some there isn't.

I'm trying to construct a `SELECT` for the table, which can be run against any of the databases. So I need a query that won't error if `MyCol1` doesn't exist.

In my head this should easy, but doesn't seem to be.

I can't change the databases or create views, so I need to handle this in a plain SQL script.

```sql
DECLARE @MyCol1Len INT = COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'MyCol1');

IF @MyCol1Len IS NULL
    PRINT 'Columns do not exist'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Columns exist'
```

This works, and prints the correct text, but when I switch the text for a `SELECT` statement, like this:

```sql
DECLARE @MyCol1Len INT = COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'MyCol1');

IF @MyCol1Len IS NULL
    PRINT 'Columns do not exist'
ELSE
    SELECT MyCol1 FROM MyTable
```

I get an error:  `Invalid column name 'MyCol1'.`

How do I have an SQL script which deals with the fact that a column might not be there, and if it's not, just return something else (like an empty string for example)..?

Comment: Something like this will switch between the real column and the computed column depending on whether `c2` is available in the table: `select t.* from (select 'Missing' as c2) v cross apply (select c1, c2 from T) t`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use dynamic SQL here:

```sql
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
          FROM sys.schemas s
               JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
               JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
          WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo'
            AND t.[name] = N'MyTable'
            AND c.[name] = N'MyCol1') 
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT MyCol1 FROM dbo.MyTable;';
ELSE
    PRINT N'Column do not exist';
```